# TypeScript optional union string type extends by default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

```
interface IBar {
  bar?: 'a' | 'b'
}

const Foo: React.FC<IBar> = (props) => {
  const {
    // should be type error, but actually no
    bar = 's'
  } = props;

  return <div />
}
```

I can avoid it using this, but i don't want to do this, cause this is overhead: FC is generic -

```
const Foo: React.FC<IBar> = (props: IBar) => {}
```

Comment: Destructuring is just initializing variables, nothing stopping `const bar` to be anything. You can explicitly state the type of the destructured object: `const { bar }: IBar = props;`

Comment: found it, very fun https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43795